# Finding an inner circle/ellipse of a 2D point cloud

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, point, point-clouds

I have a bunch of 2D-points. You can see them on the left picture. They form some sort of ring with a few bunny ears. My goal is to find the big inner cycle/ellipse, which you can see on the right side.

[image] 
[image]

What kind of algorithms are useful for such a situation.

I tried a variation of the RANSAC algorithm (taking 5 random points, form an ellipse, determine a score and repeat). I designed the scoring function in a way, that points inside the ellipse get a lot of negative points, and points outside, but very close get a lot of positive points. 
But the result is not at all promising. The algorithm finds the ring, but I get some random ellipse of the ring, not the big inner ellipse I want.

Are there any good strategies out there?

Comment: Why did you decide that points inside the ellipse get negative points? My guess is that being "close" (meaning "the distance from the center is close enough to a value you decide") should be enough to determine whether a point is what you're looking for. Then you keep track of how many point in a specified circle satisfy your condition and the circle with the most points is what you're looking for. If you only use a sum of single-point scores, you will not get good results, because the average will be a bit weird. Well, at least that's my guess.

Comment: My guess is that you should penalize any point inside the circle and favor a large radius. The score could be something like `R(c-Ni/N)`.

Comment: @user38034 How many points qualify to make a circle?

Comment: What do you mean by "big inner cycle/ellipse"? Why not make it a bit bigger in the second picture so it that more closely follows the middle of points circle?

Comment: Points outside *and far away* should also get a lot of negative points, I think.  Otherwise a bunny-ear looks as good to the objective function as the ring you want.

Comment: Can you better define "inner" circle/ellipse? Once you come up with a well defined cost function the algorithm should fall out from that. A few thoughts to consider: 1) Iterative weighted least-squares. At each iteration use a weight that minimizes points with larger radii and maximizes points with smaller radii 2)Perform stereographic projection to work with planes and not circles. Makes the problem linear and not non-linear. 3) Find the center circle (not the inner circle) then start from the center point and grow the circle until you have enough points to define a "good" fitted circle.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some Java code for **best fit circle**.

https://www.spaceroots.org/documents/circle/CircleFitter.java

```
// Copyright (c) 2005-2007, Luc Maisonobe
// All rights reserved.
// 
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with
// or without modification, are permitted provided that
// the following conditions are met:
// 
//    Redistributions of source code must retain the
//    above copyright notice, this list of conditions and
//    the following disclaimer. 
//    Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the
//    above copyright notice, this list of conditions and
//    the following disclaimer in the documentation
//    and/or other materials provided with the
//    distribution. 
//    Neither the names of spaceroots.org, spaceroots.com
//    nor the names of their contributors may be used to
//    endorse or promote products derived from this
//    software without specific prior written permission. 
// 
// THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND
// CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
// WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
// WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
// PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL
// THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
// DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
// CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
// PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF
// USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
// HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER
// IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
// NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE
// USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
// POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

package org.spaceroots;

import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/** Class fitting a circle to a set of points.
 * <p>This class implements the fitting algorithms described in the
 * paper <a
 * href="http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/circle/circle-fitting.pdf">
 * Finding the circle that best fits a set of points</a></p>
 * @author Luc Maisonobe
 */
public class CircleFitter {

  /** Test program entry point.
   * @param args command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

      BufferedReader br = null;
      switch (args.length) {
      case 0 :
        br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        break;
      case 1:
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        break;
      default :
        System.err.println("usage: java CircleFitter [file]");
        System.exit(1);
      }

      // read the points, ignoring blank lines and comment lines
      ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
      int l = 0;
      for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
        ++l;
        line = line.trim();
        if ((line.length() > 0) && (! line.startsWith("#"))) {
          // this is a data line, we expect two numerical fields
          String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
          if (fields.length != 2) {
            throw new LocalException("syntax error at line " + l + ": " + line
                                     + "(expected two fields, found"
                                     + fields.length + ")");
          }

          // parse the fields and add the point to the list
          list.add(new Point2D.Double(Double.parseDouble(fields[0]),
                                      Double.parseDouble(fields[1])));

        }
      }
      Point2D.Double[] points =
        (Point2D.Double[]) list.toArray(new Point2D.Double[list.size()]);

      DecimalFormat format =
        new DecimalFormat("000.00000000",
                          new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));

      // fit a circle to the test points
      CircleFitter fitter = new CircleFitter();
      fitter.initialize(points);
      System.out.println("initial circle: "
                         + format.format(fitter.getCenter().x)
                         + " "     + format.format(fitter.getCenter().y)
                         + " "     + format.format(fitter.getRadius()));

      // minimize the residuals
      int iter = fitter.minimize(100, 0.1, 1.0e-12);
      System.out.println("converged after " + iter + " iterations");
      System.out.println("final circle: "
                         + format.format(fitter.getCenter().x)
                         + " "     + format.format(fitter.getCenter().y)
                         + " "     + format.format(fitter.getRadius()));

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
      System.exit(1);
    } catch (LocalException le) {
      System.err.println(le.getMessage());
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  /** Build a new instance with a default current circle.
   */
  public CircleFitter() {
    center = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0);
    rHat   = 1.0;
    points = null;
  }


  /** Initialize an approximate circle based on all triplets.
   * @param points circular ring sample points
   * @exception LocalException if all points are aligned
   */
  public void initialize(Point2D.Double[] points)
    throws LocalException {

    // store the points array
    this.points = points;

    // analyze all possible points triplets
    center.x = 0.0;
    center.y = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (points.length - 2); ++i) {
      Point2D.Double p1 = (Point2D.Double) points[i];
      for (int j = i + 1; j < (points.length - 1); ++j) {
        Point2D.Double p2 = (Point2D.Double) points[j];
        for (int k = j + 1; k < points.length; ++k) {
          Point2D.Double p3 = (Point2D.Double) points[k];

          // compute the triangle circumcenter
          Point2D.Double cc = circumcenter(p1, p2, p3);
          if (cc != null) {
            // the points are not aligned, we have a circumcenter
            ++n;
            center.x += cc.x;
            center.y += cc.y;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (n == 0) {
      throw new LocalException("all points are aligned");
    }

    // initialize using the circumcenters average
    center.x /= n;
    center.y /= n;
    updateRadius();

  }

  /** Update the circle radius.
   */
  private void updateRadius() {
    rHat = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
      double dx = points[i].x - center.x;
      double dy = points[i].y - center.y;
      rHat += Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
    rHat /= points.length;
  }

  /** Compute the circumcenter of three points.
   * @param pI first point
   * @param pJ second point
   * @param pK third point
   * @return circumcenter of pI, pJ and pK or null if the points are aligned
   */
  private Point2D.Double circumcenter(Point2D.Double pI,
                                      Point2D.Double pJ,
                                      Point2D.Double pK) {

    // some temporary variables
    Point2D.Double  dIJ = new Point2D.Double(pJ.x - pI.x, pJ.y - pI.y);
    Point2D.Double  dJK = new Point2D.Double(pK.x - pJ.x, pK.y - pJ.y);
    Point2D.Double  dKI = new Point2D.Double(pI.x - pK.x, pI.y - pK.y);
    double sqI = pI.x * pI.x + pI.y * pI.y;
    double sqJ = pJ.x * pJ.x + pJ.y * pJ.y;
    double sqK = pK.x * pK.x + pK.y * pK.y;

    // determinant of the linear system: 0 for aligned points
    double det = dJK.x * dIJ.y - dIJ.x * dJK.y;
    if (Math.abs(det) < 1.0e-10) {
      // points are almost aligned, we cannot compute the circumcenter
      return null;
    }

    // beware, there is a minus sign on Y coordinate!
    return new Point2D.Double(
           (sqI * dJK.y + sqJ * dKI.y + sqK * dIJ.y) / (2 * det),
          -(sqI * dJK.x + sqJ * dKI.x + sqK * dIJ.x) / (2 * det));

  }

  /** Minimize the distance residuals between the points and the circle.
   * <p>We use a non-linear conjugate gradient method with the Polak and
   * Ribiere coefficient for the computation of the search direction. The
   * inner minimization along the search direction is performed using a
   * few Newton steps. It is worthless to spend too much time on this inner
   * minimization, so the convergence threshold can be rather large.</p>
   * @param maxIter maximal iterations number on the inner loop (cumulated
   * across outer loop iterations)
   * @param innerThreshold inner loop threshold, as a relative difference on
   * the cost function value between the two last iterations
   * @param outerThreshold outer loop threshold, as a relative difference on
   * the cost function value between the two last iterations
   * @return number of inner loop iterations performed (cumulated
   * across outer loop iterations)
   * @exception LocalException if we come accross a singularity or if
   * we exceed the maximal number of iterations
   */
  public int minimize(int iterMax,
                      double innerThreshold, double outerThreshold)
    throws LocalException {

    computeCost();
    if ((J < 1.0e-10) || (Math.sqrt(dJdx * dJdx + dJdy * dJdy) < 1.0e-10)) {
      // we consider we are already at a local minimum
      return 0;
    }

    double previousJ = J;
    double previousU = 0.0, previousV = 0.0;
    double previousDJdx = 0.0, previousDJdy = 0.0;
    for (int iterations = 0; iterations < iterMax;) {

      // search direction
      double u = -dJdx;
      double v = -dJdy;
      if (iterations != 0) {
        // Polak-Ribiere coefficient
        double beta =
          (dJdx * (dJdx - previousDJdx) + dJdy * (dJdy - previousDJdy))
        / (previousDJdx * previousDJdx + previousDJdy * previousDJdy);
        u += beta * previousU;
        v += beta * previousV;
      }
      previousDJdx = dJdx;
      previousDJdy = dJdy;
      previousU    = u;
      previousV    = v;

      // rough minimization along the search direction
      double innerJ;
      do {
        innerJ = J;
        double lambda = newtonStep(u, v);
        center.x += lambda * u;
        center.y += lambda * v;
        updateRadius();
        computeCost();
      } while ((++iterations < iterMax)
               && ((Math.abs(J - innerJ) / J) > innerThreshold));

      // global convergence test
      if ((Math.abs(J - previousJ) / J) < outerThreshold) {
        return iterations;
      }
      previousJ = J;

    }

    throw new LocalException("unable to converge after "
                             + iterMax + " iterations");

  }

  /** Compute the cost function and its gradient.
   * <p>The results are stored as instance attributes.</p>
   */
  private void computeCost() throws LocalException {
    J    = 0;
    dJdx = 0;
    dJdy = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
      double dx = points[i].x - center.x;
      double dy = points[i].y - center.y;
      double di = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      if (di < 1.0e-10) {
        throw new LocalException("cost singularity:"
                                 + " point at the circle center");
      }
      double dr    = di - rHat;
      double ratio = dr / di;
      J    += dr * (di + rHat);
      dJdx += dx * ratio;
      dJdy += dy * ratio;
    }
    dJdx *= 2.0;
    dJdy *= 2.0;
  }

  /** Compute the length of the Newton step in the search direction.
   * @param u abscissa of the search direction
   * @param v ordinate of the search direction
   * @return value of the step along the search direction
   */
  private double newtonStep(double u, double v) {

    // compute the first and second derivatives of the cost
    // along the specified search direction
    double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sumFac = 0, sumFac2R = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
      double dx     = center.x - points[i].x;
      double dy     = center.y - points[i].y;
      double di     = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      double coeff1 = (dx * u + dy * v) /  di;
      double coeff2 = di - rHat;
      sum1         += coeff1 * coeff2;
      sum2         += coeff2 / di;
      sumFac       += coeff1;
      sumFac2R     += coeff1 * coeff1 / di;
    }

    // step length attempting to nullify the first derivative
    return -sum1 / ((u * u + v * v) * sum2
                    - sumFac * sumFac / points.length
                    + rHat * sumFac2R);

  }

  /** Get the circle center.
   * @return circle center
   */
  public Point2D.Double getCenter() {
    return center;
  }

  /** Get the circle radius.
   * @return circle radius
   */
  public double getRadius() {
    return rHat;
  }

  /** Local exception class for algorithm errors. */
  public static class LocalException extends Exception {
    /** Build a new instance with the supplied message.
     * @param message error message
     */
    public LocalException(String message) {
      super(message);
    }
  }

  /** Current circle center. */
  private Point2D.Double center;

  /** Current circle radius. */
  private double rHat;

  /** Circular ring sample points. */
  private Point2D.Double[] points;

  /** Current cost function value. */
  private double J;

  /** Current cost function gradient. */
  private double dJdx;
  private double dJdy;

}
```

**EDIT** Once you have a best fit circle you could shrink it until some ratio of inner to outer points is met. Or you could remove all of the points outside of the circle and run the best fit circle algorithm again, repeating this process until you have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: This won't return a circle inside the points, but will more likely have half the points inside the circle and half the points outside.

Comment: @GuyGreer - once you have a best fit circle you could shrink it until whatever, currently undefined, percentage of points is outside of it. This question isn't fleshed out enough to give an exact answer.